# How to find all the NFTs, ERC721 and ERC1155, owned by address of *a certain collection*?

Tags: ethers.js, nft

How to find all the NFTs of **a certain collection**, ERC721 and ERC1155, owned by address ? In ethers.js

**update #1**

Let's say, I'm an owner of an NFT collection who sells them via my website.

When user comes to my website and logs in with his wallet,  won't I be able to find out what NFTs of *my* collection he's a holder of?

---

I could upgrade an NFT smart contract if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires indexing the blockchain. This is fairly simple using Moralis APIs. https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/how-to-get-nft-owners-by-an-address

Alternative, you can do this using ethers.js:

```
const { ethers } = require('ethers');

const networkUrl = 'https://eth-mainnet.your-moralis-server.com/APIKEY';
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(networkUrl);
const contractAddress = '0x...'; // Replace with the actual contract address
const abi = [...]; // Replace with the ABI of the ERC721 or ERC1155 contract

const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, provider);
```

For ERC721:
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/ffceb3cd988874369806139ae9e59d2e2a93daec/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L60

```
const ownerAddress = '0x...'; // Replace with the owner's address

const balance = await contract.balanceOf(ownerAddress);
```

For ERC1155:
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/ffceb3cd988874369806139ae9e59d2e2a93daec/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol#L78

```
const ownerAddress = '0x...'; // Replace with the owner's address
const tokenIds = [1, 2, 3]; // Replace with the desired token IDs

const balances = await contract.balanceOfBatch([ownerAddress], tokenIds);
```

The balance or balances variable will contain the number of NFTs owned by the address. You can then loop through the token IDs.

Comment: Another question: How can an owner of a **collection**  list all the NFTs in it?

Comment: @lordarora I'm deleting the comment you flagged. If you are affiliated with Moralis, you also need to mention it in your answer.

Comment: if I was I would have but I'll take that as a compliment @eth

Comment: *Another question: How can an owner of a collection list all the NFTs in it?*

Answer (score 0):

Use a Node as a service that provides additional NFT endpoints. I like to use alchemy. It provides the [getNFTsForOwner](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/getnftsforowner-v3) endpoint that does the job.